# How can I generate a non-UTF-8 Character Set

Tags: utf-8

One of my requirement says "Text Box Name should accept only UTF-8 Character set". I want to perform a negative test by entering a non UTF-8 character set. How can I do this?

Comment: Via a UI you will have a hard time doing this. You will need to somehow doing it programatically.

Comment: Start by defining your *programming language*, environment and/or context. This will very much vary depending on what system you're working with/on/in.

Answer (score 14):

If you are asking how to construct a non-UTF-8 character, that should be easy from [this definition from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description):

[image: utf8 definition]

For code points U+0000 through U+007F, each codepoint is one byte long and looks like this:

```
0xxxxxxx   // a
```

For code points U+0080 through U+07FF, each codepoint is two bytes long and look like this:

```
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx  // b
```

And so on.

So, to construct an illegal UTF-8 character that is one byte long, the highest bit must be 1 (to be different from pattern a) and the second highest bit must be 0 (to be different from pattern b):

```
10xxxxxx
```

or

```
111xxxxx
```

Which also differs from both patterns.

With the same logic, you can construct illegal codeunit sequences which are more than two bytes long.

You did not tag a language, but I had to test it, so I used Java:

```
for (int i=0;i<255;i++) {
    System.out.println( 
        i + " " + 
        (byte)i + " " + 
        Integer.toHexString(i) + " " + 
        String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0') + " " + 
        new String(new byte[]{(byte)i},"UTF-8")
    );
}
```

0 to 31 are non-printable characters, then 32 is space, followed by printable characters:

```
...
31 31 1f 00011111 
32 32 20 00100000  
33 33 21 00100001 !
...
126 126 7e 01111110 ~
127 127 7f 01111111 
128 -128 80 10000000 �
```

`delete` is `0x7f` and after it, from 128 inclusively up to 254 no valid characters are printed. You can see from the [UTF-8 chartable](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl) also:

[image]

Codepoint `U+007F` is represented with one byte `0x7F` (bits `01111111`), while codepoint `U+0080` is represented with two bytes `0xC2 0x80` (bits `11000010 10000000`).

If you are not familiar with UTF-8 I strongly recommend reading this excellent article:

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)