# How can I generate non-UTF-8 string / char in Java for testing purposes?

Tags: java, utf-8

I think I have looked everywhere. Have found some examples in Ruby but nothing coherent in Java.

How can I generate non-UTF-8 string / char in Java for testing purposes?

Specifically, I have a `json` file that holds different key-values related to some translations mechanism we use (so, a lot of languages involved), this `json` parsed with some mapper that we have.

I want to check if the mapper returns the proper values in case a non-UTF data encountered in the `json`.

So, I would like to use it in approach like:

```
String expectedValue = "FooBarNonUtf8";
String actualValue = jsonReader.readFrom("file", "key"); //should parse non-UTF correctly
assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
```

Comment: what is your definition of *non UTF-8*?

Comment: Since UTF-8 is meant to comprise all characters (even emojis) it's a little hard to generate one that isn't in UTF-8. Or do you mean another encoding, like Latin-1, i.e. any encoding except UTF-8?

Comment: UTF-8 is a character encoding. It transforms characters (which don't have any encoding), into bytes. Not sure what you mean by "non-UTF-8 string", since a String contains characters, not bytes.

Comment: surely you need to construct it as bytes. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031620/how-can-i-generate-a-non-utf-8-character-set

Comment: Strings and characters in Java itself are always UTF-16... Encoding is only relevant when transforming to or from bytes. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet *since a String contains characters, not bytes*, well  *internally though* is a different story since java-9

Comment: @MarkRotteveel *not* since java-9

Comment: @Eugene that is an implementation detail. The public API of a String allows getting characters, and all Unicode code points are supported. How these code points are stored internally doesn't really matter here.

Comment: @JBNizet right, reason I said *internally*

Comment: @Eugene Well, you are right that the in-memory encoding changed, but characters are still UTF-16 in their numbering and usage (eg surrogate pairs etc).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel well if there is a surrogate pair it is UTF-16 already - 2 bytes, if there isn't it's LATIN_1, thus a single byte

Comment: @Eugene You're talking about the in-memory encoding again. I'm talking about what characters represent.

Comment: Do you want an invalid UTF-8 `byte[]` to test if you can convert it to `String`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301402/example-invalid-utf8-string

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've added some details about the flow I have.

Comment: "jsonReader … should parse non-UTF correctly": Whatever do you mean? JSON documents exchanged between system are required to be UTF-8-encoded. Isn't invalid simply invalid? Send it back.

Comment: @TomBlodget that's the reason I'm trying to test it - we received a non-UTF value from the JSON (it's a lot of files which holds multilingual translations to our product).

Comment: So wouldn't the correct behavior for a file that fails to meet the expectation that it can be decoded to text using UTF-8 an exception? Then wouldn't the correct behavior for text that fails to meet the expectation that it's valid JSON be an exception?

Comment: @TomBlodget exactly, but for that I need to create file with non-valid UTF8 content and verify it in test. That' exactly what my q is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java made the following design decision, after the catastrophes with encoding in C/C++ (at that point in history):

- `String, char, Reader, Writer` are for handling Unicode text, char is UTF-16, two bytes.
- `byte[], InputStream, OutputStream` are for binary data, that given some encoding/Charset, could be text.

So you actually can only *abuse* String/char, and it is almost guaranteed that there will be corrupted data (some chars have special structuring meaning for UTF-*).

The solution is to encode the binary data in for instance Base64.

```
byte[] b = ...
String s = Base64.getEncoder().encode(b);
```

There are some different encoders, and you can set properties like line wrapping, padding and so on.

Or you might be more comfortable with a hexadecimal representation.